# Modal don't show up correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I'm having a problem with a modal which doesn't show up correctly

https://github.com/gothraven/Problem

When i check the code source of the page i have this
"test.html" and it works fine in a saperate html file when i copy and past it.

but this is the original php file "modif_ques.php" with the included files
modifc_popup.php ,addc_popup.php

I checked in the page inspector and i found this, i don't know how this happened
[(check here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hk4Bw.png)

```
<div id="modif_data_Modal" class="modal fade" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">a lot of things here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

when i click it becomes

```
<div id="modif_data_Modal" class="modal fade in" style="display: block; padding-right: 19px;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">a lot of things here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to make sure of <meta> links. If you've not copied them, you should include them in the new page.

Comment: how would i do that? i've add the header.php so you can see guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer which was a problem in my code

i removed this, which was a mistake

```
<form></form>
```

and changed this

```
<a href='modif_champ.php?cid=$row[cid]' class ='close' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modif_data_Modal'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></i></a>
```

with this

```
<button class='close' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modif_data_Modal'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></i></button>
```

i don't know but apearently to show the modal proparly we need to use `<button>` button instead of `<a>`

Comment: so you got it fixed? if yes please mark this post as answered. Regarding the <button> and <a>. It depends on the selector. If you check the JS for it or CSS, in CSS close.button is different from a.button. So, this might was the case!